# How to compile using scope variables using directives

Tags: angularjs-directive

I have the following code inside my directive.

```
scope.value = 5;
alert(scope.value);
var compiled = $compile("<div><h1>{{value}}</h1></div>")(scope);
alert(compiled[0].outerHTML)
```

The first alert value is 5, however, the second one shows...

```
<div><h1>{{value}}</h1></div>
```

How do I get it to recognize the value?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think alert stops executing so js did not compiled yet.

See this http://plnkr.co/edit/iaJsO8qPk1Knoh1mXRjy?p=preview

```
setTimeout(function(){
   alert(compiled[0].outerHTML);
 },100);
```

I added timeout to alert compile so I can see the needle html.

Do console.log(compiled[0].outerHTML);

Comment: I had the same problem with the angular UI modal (dialogService.openModal(compiled[0].outerHTML);) which is what I was really trying to solve. This seems a little hacky (is it really pausing for 100 milliseconds?) but worked great! Thanks!